# Error in Netbeans IDE To run Applet Project

Tags: java, netbeans, applet

I am trying to run my applet in netbeans IDE But browser is not opening automatically. If I copy address to browser it is running. Project runs in localhost.

Error is as follows---

```
  java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle    
  org.openide.util.NbBundle$PBundle, key MSG_win_browser_invocation_failed
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:450)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:407)
at org.openide.util.NbBundle.getMessage(NbBundle.java:642)
at 
  org.netbeans.modules.extbrowser.NbDdeBrowserImpl$URLDisplayer.dispatchURL
  (NbDdeBrowserImpl.java:438)
at org.netbeans.modules.extbrowser.NbDdeBrowserImpl$URLDisplayer.run
   (NbDdeBrowserImpl.java:354)

  [catch] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a known issue in the Netbeans.

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=237542

It has a lots of dulicates over different versions, looks like they fixed in the nightly build, but it is still not released.

Comment: also I am not able to report problem send button is grayed in netbeans.

Comment: That's fine... 
With [the amount of duplicate bugs to this issue](http://statistics.netbeans.org/exceptions/detail.do?id=203661) I doubt that you reporting one more time would be of any help.

If you wish, you could download one of the [nightly builds](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/nightly/) that have your problem fixed (was fixed in build *201502130001* )

Or you could just wait until a new version is released.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error while accessing the Sonar Runner: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle org.openide.util.NbBundle$PBundle, key SonarRunner.error

Resolution :

```
1. Ran the sonarqube bat file ...\sonarqube-6.4\bin\windows-x86-64\StartSonar.bat
2. Execute "mvn sonar:sonar" in the project folder
3. After this Get Issues with Sonar Runner should work fine.
```

[image]